# How do you automate DevExpress Combo Boxes with Selenuim/Watir?

Tags: selenium, combobox, devexpress, watir

DevExpress builds combo boxes in a very odd way.  The standard identification built in to Selenuim and Watir (including Page Objects) does not see it as a Select List.
So how can you automate these successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it turns out, DevExpress builds combo boxes as a text box with several layered tables associated with it but not under the text box in the HTML tree.
interactions are all done via embedded scripts.

I found the simplest way to automate this object is to identify the text box and the lowest table containing the list of items (3rd table down).

for example (using Watir and Page Objects)

```
table(:list,:id => 'ComboBoxValue_DDD_L_LBT')
text_field(:state, :id => 'ComboBoxValue_I') #:name => 'State')
```

I have not found a way to get better IDs at these levels, but we are working that issue.
Then your select code looks like this:

```
self.state_element.click
row = list_element.find { |row| row[0].text == value }
row.click
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that with Selenium, you can execute arbitrary javascript in the client to query and set the control's state (if the client-side is enabled for the control).  Here's how I did so to extract (and set) the selected text from a combobox named localeSelectList:

```
// unit test code, c#
[TestMethod]
public void SomeTestMethod()
{
    IWebDriver ff = new FirefoxDriver();
    ff.Navigate().GoToUrl(homeUrl);
    // find the element as an iWebElement
    IWebElement localeBox =  ff.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#localeSelectList"));
    Assert.IsTrue(localeBox.Enabled);

    // get the text from the control via javascript
    var locale = Util.GetControlText(ff, localeSelectList);
    Assert.IsTrue(locale == "English");
    // set the text in the control via javascript
    Util.SetControlText(ff, localeSelectList, "German");
    // verify the text was set
    locale = Util.GetControlText(ff, localeSelectList);
    Assert.IsTrue(locale == "German");
}

// helper methods, Util class
static public string GetControlText(IWebDriver driver, string controlName)
   {
       string script = string.Format("return {0}.GetText();", controlName);
       var controlText = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(script);
       return controlText.ToString();
   }
static public void SetControlText(IWebDriver driver, string controlName, string controlText)
   {
       string script = string.Format("{0}.SetValue('{1}');", controlName, controlText);
       ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(script);
   }
```

It's not quite the same thing as interacting with the extensions via primitives (clicks, keystrokes, etc) as it won't fire the event handlers for these events, but if your extension uses 'valueChanged' events instead of primitive handlers it's pretty close to the same.
Also note: you can use client-side javascript to find and return elements using jquery/css selectors and ids, as follows:

```
IWebElement element = (IWebElement) ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return $('#.myElementId');")
```

Comment: I am trying to get my Devs to expose some JS methods.  I'll try this once that happens.

Answer (score 0):

That's right with several layered tables, but I would like to add that they are only visible when combobox is clicked. First

```
            var cmbParameterGruppen = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("phContent_ParameterGruppenComboBox_I"));
            cmbParameterGruppen.Click();
```

and then

```
            var tblItems = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("phContent_ParameterGruppenComboBox_DDD_L_LBT"));

            var parameterGruppen = tblItems.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*"));
            var count = parameterGruppen.Count;
            Debug.WriteLine($"Count = {count}");
            if(count > 0)
                parameterGruppen[count - 1].Click();
```

I select hier last row.